# Vue Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In this part of code I want to show values of object.

```
 <div class="container">
    <h3>Finance</h3>
    <p>{{currentFinance.finance_id}}</p>
    <p>{{currentFinance.name}}</p>
    <p>{{currentFinance.description}}</p>
</div>
 ....
 methods: {

        getFinance(id) {
            FinanceService.getFinanceByTrip(somevalue, id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.currentFinance = response.data;
                    console.log('check data: ',this.currentFinance);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        }
    },
    created() {     
        this.getFinance(this.$route.params.parentId);
    }
```

In postman request works correctly. In logs values show, but error will be first then log with values. Error connect with `<p>{{currentFinance.finance_id}}</p>`. What could be wrong? (fields of "currentFinance" have correct name)

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from the code you posted. You don't call `.id` anywhere.

Comment: Try displaying `div.container` conditionally, using `v-if="currentFinance"`

Comment: instead of created try calling the function from mounted